# Using configurable properties in Java web applications

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, configuration

I have a java based web application deployed on Tomcat 6. I need to make some properties as configurable. Currently i have created a config.properties file and load that file in a static Properties object.

I want to know if there is any other efficient method or framework to use configurable properties in Java web applications?

Comment: Even I use a static class to load from my properties file and I believe that is the best!

Comment: Configurable by whom? By operations? By an admin user through the user interface? ...?

Comment: By operations in production environment, by support team in staging environment and by developers in development environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sample;

This is sample Resource.properties file that place in com.package;

```
     name=John
     email=john@company.com
     description=John is a Java software developer
```

And access likes this;

```
     private static final String PROPERTIES_FILE = "com/package/Resource.properties";

     Properties properties = new Properties();  
     properties.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(PROPERTIES_FILE));  
     String name = props.getProperty("name");  
     String email = props.getProperty("email");  
     String description = props.getProperty("description");
```

The other framework to use configurable properties is [JSF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/javaserverfaces-139869.html).This [sample](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-and-resource-bundles-example/) is the usages of properties in JSF.

Comment: i'm already using this apporach. The problem with this apporach is that either i have to load properties whenever a request is made to the application (i think bad apporach) or i have to load it in a static properties object and it won't get updated when the file changes and i'll have to reload the application

Answer (score 0):

Another option you might have would be to have one class with all your constants of your projects defined in it. This will provide you with a centralized way in which you can configure your application effectively and efficiently.

That being said however, I think that using the configuration files is the best option since (I do not think) that you would have to recompile your code each time after changing.

EDIT: Seeing some of the comments above, what you could make would be to have a separate table  in your database in which you would be able to store all your constants. You can then make this table available to system administrators and other support personnel through a back end web interface.

Comment: Code can't be recomplied in production environment, having a centralized class isn't an option here

Comment: @orak: I thought so. If that is the case then you will either have to keep using the config file or else, the back-end system I suggested. The advantage of the back end system is that it does not require access to the machine.

Answer (score 0):

The enterprise level answer would be to load your configuration through an integration framework like **Spring**. If your application is fairly small I wouldn't necessarily recommend it, though.

Answer (score 0):

Loading properties with Spring Framework:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:configuration.properties"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Here is configutaion for connection pool -->
    <!-- Those ${} properties are from the configuration.properties file -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${db.user}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${db.pass}"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```